# SPOJ Foodies Java Code Wrong Answer

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem Statement:**

> There are N-counters available and each counter has a specified number of chicken nuggets.
>   The cost of each nugget being bought at any counter is same as the number of nuggets that are still remaining at the counter at that point of time( Inclusive of the nugget being bought ).
>
> Pre wants to have M most costly nuggets. What will be the total amount required to buy M most costly nuggets.

See [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FOODIES/) for a more detailed problem statement.

Here is my JAVA code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int t,n,i,max;
        long ans,m,k;
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());;
        while(t!=0)
        {
          ans = 0;
          n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());;
          int a[] = new int[n];
          int b[] = new int[100005];
          int c[] = new int[100005];
          StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());

          i = 0;
          while(tk.hasMoreTokens()){
            a[i] =Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());
            i++;
          }

          m = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
          max = a[0];
          for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(a[i]>max){
              max = a[i];
            }
          }
          for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            b[a[i]]++;
          }

          c[max] = b[max];

          for(i=max-1;i>=1;i--){
            if(b[i]!=0){
              c[i] = c[i+1] + b[i];
            }
            else{
            c[i] = c[i+1];
            }
          }
          k = 0;

          for(i=max;i>=1;i--){
            if(c[i]>=m-k){
              ans = ans + (m-k)*i;
              break;
            }
            else{
              ans = ans + c[i]*i;
              k = k + c[i];
            }
          }
          System.out.println(ans);
          t--;
        }
    }
}
```

It gives correct answers for simple test cases but giving **Wrong Answer** on SPOJ. Is there a problem with my logic or is JAVA itself producing wrong answer on SPOJ? If there is a problem with JAVA, then should I quit coding in JAVA for competitive coding problems?

**Edit:** Removed `Arrays.sort()`. Replaced with Counting Sort. Updated the code. Still getting **WA**

**Edit2:** Converted all the arrays to `long` type. Passes all tests. Can't figure out why. Can anyone tell **Why??**

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with java on SPOJ and no, you should not quit coding in JAVA. Most competitors compete in c++, but almost all sites support java as programming language and many people use it. I personally use java for some problems that are harder to implement in c++.

Now on the second question - there are multiple problems with your implementation and also I think your code will be too slow on the worst case(try to figure which one is the worst).

Comment: Sorting was unnecessary. I removed it. Still getting `WA`. I tried SPOJ Toolkit and all the tricky sample tests from there, ran successfully on my local box. But SPOJ showing `WA`

Comment: Have you tried running the worst case locally? Does it produce the expected answer? I don't want to give you further tips because after all the point in SPOJ is you to solve the problems on your own

Comment: Used all the tests from http://spojtoolkit.com/history/FOODIES. There are worst case tests too. My code passed all of them

Comment: @User_Targaryen some of them are edge cases, some of them are only random cases. However I think it is impossible to paste the worst case there

Comment: Converted all my arrays to `long` type. All tests passed!!! Can't figure what just happened!!!

Comment: @User_Targaryen your problem was several integer overflows when computing intermediate values. That is why I was advising you to run the maximum case locally.